# In Proc Timeseries, how to output all ids even if there aren't any occurrences?

Tags: sas

I have a transactional table with events since 1999, which I want to convert into a time series. However, when I run proc timeseries, it only keeps client ids which have occurrences between my start and end dates. How can I keep all ids, filling those with no occurrences in the period with zeroes?

Example warning message:

```
WARNING: There are no usable input observations.
NOTE: The above message was for the following BY group:
      id=1
```

I actually solved this issue in an ugly way, but I'm hoping there's a better one:

1. Find out which ids were discarded in the time series
2. Find out the intervals created by proc timeseries
3. Manual cartesian product (discarded_ids x intervals)
4. Append

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix would be to populate your table with the missing date using a time dimension...
Like inserting record in your table for the proc timeserie with null values and at least   id=1